# Isolating Player in Kinect Depth Camera

Tags: c++, kinect

I'm trying to isolate a single player through the Kinect depth camera.  I'm opening an `NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_DEPTH_AND_PLAYER_INDEX` stream to process the player/depth info.  The code that I'm using to draw a player is this:

```
if (LockedRect.Pitch != 0 ) {
      USHORT* curr = (USHORT*) LockedRect.pBits;
      const USHORT* dataEnd = curr + ((width/2)*(height/2));
      index = 0;

      while (curr < dataEnd && playerId != 0) {
        USHORT depth     = *curr;
        USHORT realDepth = NuiDepthPixelToDepth(depth);
        BYTE intensity = 255;
        USHORT player    = NuiDepthPixelToPlayerIndex(depth);


        // Only colour in the player
        if (player == playerId) {
          for (int i = index; i < index + 4; i++)
            dest[i] = intensity;
        }
        else {
          for (int i = index; i < index + 4; i++)
            dest[i] = 0;
        }
        index += 4;
        curr += 1;                                                                
      }    
 }
```

`dest` is an OpenGL texture.

The problem I'm having is that the variable `player` changes when a second person steps into the frame, and causes the person drawn in the texture to be the new person.

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured out how to do it.

I needed to get the skeletal ID (0 through 5) which maps to depth pixel user (1 through 6).  So when the sensor found a skeleton, it saved the ID, and set that to playerId.  PlayerId is only cleared when its associated skeleton is lost by sensor.